# Deployment failed using AzureDevops

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm following this Azure Devops lab: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/github-azurepipelines/#task-4-embedding-automated

but when I'm deploying the app, this error appears:

```
There were errors in your deployment.     
Error code: DeploymentFailed.  
[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
[error]Details:  
[error]BadRequest: {  
"error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "There was an unexpected InternalServerError. Please try again
later. x-ms-correlation-request-id: a016b467-fbd6-4851-a411-30f253ad4854"  
}  
} undefined  
[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

I don't know which parameter is wrong, I tried to make manual deployments and still it fails.

Attached is the deployment detail I used to make the deployment.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "p_environment": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_separator": {
        "defaultValue": "-",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_site_prefix": {
        "defaultValue": "githubci",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_site_web_name": {
        "defaultValue": "web",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_comosdb_name": {
        "defaultValue": "db",
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "site_web_name": "[concat(parameters('p_site_prefix'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_site_web_name'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_environment'))]",
    "comosdb_default_name": "[concat(parameters('p_site_prefix'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_comosdb_name'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_environment'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "kind": "MongoDB",
        "name": "[variables('comosdb_default_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "defaultExperience": "MongoDB"
        },
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('comosdb_default_name')]",
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "consistencyPolicy": {
                "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
                "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
                "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[variables('site_web_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('site_web_name')]",
            "reserved": false,
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "COSMOS_DB_NAME",
                        "value":"[variables('comosdb_default_name')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "COSMOS_DB_AUTH_KEY",
                        "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', variables('comosdb_default_name')), '2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                        "value": "8.9.4"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/', variables('comosdb_default_name'))]"
        ]
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "web": {
            "type": "string",
             "value": "[variables('site_web_name')]"
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the full deployment process from the beginning to end. I also got the same error. It seems that this tutorial creates a new resource group, but did not create a new web-app inside that resource group to deploy. To successfully deploy, create a webapp inside your resource group with the name "githubci-web-" and run the deployment again. It will be successful.

Comment: Now is working perfectly! as you mention it is MANDATORY to create a webapp inside your resource group on Azure with the name "githubci-web-" and run the deployment again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. Happy coding :)